# Is it possible in Scala to write an expression that placed in a function parameter, defaults the parameter value?

Tags: scala

I have the following constructor

```
class Indexer(
  index: String,
  host: String,
  port: Int = DEFAULT_ES_PORT)
```

I only want to pass the port parameter if it isn't -1, otherwise I want to use the default value. 
My naive approach was:

```
val esi = new Indexer(
  index = es.index,
  host = es.getHost,
  port = if (es.getPort != -1) es.getPort
)
```

but on the 4th line i get a compiler error of course:

```
type mismatch; found : Unit required: Int Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
```

because the else branch evaluates to Unit. 
Of course I could be writing this:

```
val esi = if (es.getPort != -1) {
    new Indexer(
      index = es.index,
      host = es.getHost,
      port = es.getPort
    ) 
  } else {
    new Indexer(
      index = es.index,
      host = es.getHost
    )
  }
```

But I wonder if there is a more concise way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `if (es.getPort != -1) es.getPort` is missing the `else` clause, so that the resulting type of this expression is `Unit`.

You could solve by providing the `else` clause:

```
val esi = new Indexer(
  index = es.index,
  host = es.getHost,
  port = if (es.getPort != -1) es.getPort else DEFAULT_ES_PORT
)
```

This of course would mean that you need to use the `DEFAULT_ES_PORT` in your caller's code.

An alternative is to use for the parameter `port` the type `Option[Int]` and use `None`, if you want the default and convert it to an `Int` within the constructor of `Indexer`.

Comment: Nice Approach, and with this approach you don't even need to give default value to the port in your class Indexer.

Answer (score 1):

I would Prefer Pattern Matching :

```
val esi = es.getPort match  {
      case -1 => new Indexer(es.index,es.getHost) 
      case x => new Indexer(es.index,es.getHost,x)
  }
```

Comment: I totally forgot that I can use pattern matching too. It sure looks nicer than my if else approach :)